# How do I get a Huawei E1550 dongle working?

Tags: 12.04, modem-manager, huawei

I need help making my E1550 dongle work on Ubuntu 12.04. When I connect the dongle to my laptop, it is recognized by the Network-Manager and is listed as one of the options. But each time I try to connect, it instantly disconnects.
Does anyone know how I can make the dongle work?

Comment: You have your provider settings configured properly? I'm having the same dongle and works fine for me without any special settings except [one problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/110112/unable-to-connect-to-internet-with-3g-usb-dongle-for-particular-isp/).

Answer (score 1):

I found a topic in the [german Ubuntu Users Wiki](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Mobiler_Datentransfer#Die-Verbindung-wird-nach-wenigen-Sekunden-wieder-getrennt) describing your problem. They suggest commenting out a range of lines in `/etc/ppp/options`:

```
lcp-echo-interval 30         # range start
...
lcp-echo-failure 4           # range end
```

From my experience with different dongles and Ubuntu versions I would like to propose another solution:

1. Buy a [MiFi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MiFi) or [Huawei E5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huawei_E5), those are mobile hotspots providing internet access for 3 to 5 devices at the same time. Everything that needs to be configured will be done on the hotspot and you simply connect via WiFi or USB.
2. If your notebook is equipped with a SIM slot and antennas buy an internal modem card, I never had issues with that.

Answer (score 0):

Open Network manager, 
Edit connection, 
Click Mobile Broadband, 
Select your existing entry or if not create new entry, 
Properly select Network provider and from Mobile broadband plan select exact plan and APN, 
In Almost all cases your service provider will be listed, but if not call details of APN and provider name from your service provider customer care, 
Save close and connect again.

This should be enough to log you into internet

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my updated ubuntu (12.04 64-bit) after upgrade from 11.10 (modem worked without any hints).

To solve this problem, use terminal (linux or even windows - hyper terminal) to access AT commands and turn device to modem-only mode: AT^U2DIAG=0

In case you'll need other modes, you can turn it back:

AT^U2DIAG=0     (modem only)

AT^U2DIAG=1     (modem + CD-ROM)

AT^U2DIAG=255   (modem + CD-ROM + Card Reader)

AT^U2DIAG=256   (modem + Card Reader)