# New Ubuntu 12.04 Installation not detecting Huawei E1550

Tags: 12.04, huawei

Huawei E1550 (internet Device: ISP Etisalat, Egypt) is not showing-up on Ubuntu 12.04.

Any Idea?

via `lsusb`  it is recognized as:

```
Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd E169/E620/E800 HSDAP Modem.
```

However, in Media folder it does not  show at all.

Can Mode-switching be applied successfully?

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of possible solutions in the link below which was a similar question asked about the same modem.

[How do I get a Huawei E1550 dongle working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136898/how-do-i-get-a-huawei-e1550-dongle-working)

Comment: Can Mode-switching be applied successfully?  Thanks,

Comment: Looks like it was done already but to be sure check you have the most up to date version on your machine in the software centre. Details of the current version and help in installing it can be found at http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/ Hope this helps.

Comment: crossover and system update fixed it.